# How to group rows by date in a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe `news_df` with titles of articles and dates and I want to group the articles that were written the same day on the same line.

```
    name
date    
2019-01-17 14:41:00 Forte hausse de l'indice Philly Fed en janvier
2019-01-17 14:36:00 Baisse des inscriptions hebdomadaires au chômage
2019-01-16 22:30:00 Wall Street finit en hausse, Goldman Sachs et ...
2019-01-16 16:14:00 Wall Street, soutenue par les résultats de ban...
2019-01-16 14:36:00 Baisse de 1% des prix à l'import en décembre
...
```

I tried :

```
news_df.resample('D', on='name')
```

But it gives me a TypeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-bdfd57eadc21> in <module>
----> 1 news_df.resample('D', on='name')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base, on, level)
   7108                      axis=axis, kind=kind, loffset=loffset,
   7109                      convention=convention,
-> 7110                      base=base, key=on, level=level)
   7111         return _maybe_process_deprecations(r,
   7112                                            how=how,

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in resample(obj, kind, **kwds)
       1146     """ create a TimeGrouper and return our resampler """
       1147     tg = TimeGrouper(**kwds)
    -> 1148     return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
       1149 
       1150 

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in _get_resampler(self, obj, kind)
       1274         raise TypeError("Only valid with DatetimeIndex, "
       1275                         "TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, "
    -> 1276                         "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
       1277 
       1278     def _get_grouper(self, obj, validate=True):

    TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Comment: So presumably you copy/pasted that error straight into Google, found the same resources we will find, but they didn't work?

Comment: check my answer below please

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, exactly the same if yours didn't worked as well. The methods I tried were found thanks to Google. I took the liberty to try some from [googueule.fr](http://www.googueule.fr/) as well but it was more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get date out of the index to column    
df = df.reset_index()
# optional
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# groupby and output group rows as list
df = df.groupby('date')['name'].apply(list)
```

**EDIT:**

you need to set strptime format to whatever format of your input date is.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H%M%S").strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: Thank you! But how to not take hours and second into account ?